# Maven - How to work with "*.properties" files after build?

Tags: java, maven

I have these folders in my project structure

- /src/main/java
- /src/main/resources

In the "resources" folder I have 2 files: `"config.properties"` and `"logging.properties"`.

And I have the following "" in my pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <resources>      
          <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
          </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <archive>
              <manifest>
                <mainClass>myapp.Main</mainClass>
              </manifest>
            </archive>
            <descriptorRefs>
              <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
          </configuration>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>make-assembly</id>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

When I run "mvn clean package", it does generate the "target" folder with the jar and the "classes" folder containg the properties file as mentioned above.

To read one of the properties files (after clicking on a Button), I'm using the following code:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("logging.properties"));                        
String logFolder = prop.getProperty("myApp.property");    
//Do something with 'logFolder'
```

It runs OK.

But if I change the "myApp.property" in "logging.properties" file, **the change doesn't affect the "logFolder" value**.

What must I do to be able to dinamically change the property value and make my application read the new value **WITHOUT RECOMPILING THE PROJECT**?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue.

The other answers are correct. The real problem (I think) is with this "maven-assembly-plugin" that I was using to build.

For some reason, it does not read my properties files after build, maybe I was doing something wrong with it.

So, I changed my `<build>` script in my `pom.xml` to the following:

```
<build>
    <finalName>myapp</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.1</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>copy-dependencies</id>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <configuration>
                <includeEmptyDirs>true</includeEmptyDirs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                                    <include>logs</include>
                                </includes>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>                            
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.properties</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>myApp.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Class-Path>.</Class-Path>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/logs</include>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>
                <include>**/*.gif</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

In short: I replaced the "maven-assembly-plugin" with "maven-dependency-plugin" (I'm using  an Oracle DB in this project), "maven-resources-plugin" (copying all of my resources to "/target" folder after build) and the "maven-jar-plugin" setting the "Class-path" property to ".".

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke respective plugins manually:

```
mvn resources:resources maven-assembly-plugin:single
```

Though this is not the best option anyway. It's better to eliminate re-packaging all together for local deploys:

1. Just start the app in IDE instead of building a JAR. IDE will detect changes in the configs.
2. And in general allow overriding your variables with either env vars or system variables. So after reading the file also check if the values are overriden and use those.

For remote deploys we usually don't keep configuration files in JAR (you don't want to keep PRD passwords in there, right?). So deploying to remote envs should use config files from restricted sources. This means that the app needs to be able to read configs that are not inside JAR.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I added to my pom file so Maven loads the resources into the jar at the root level.

```
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/my-resources</directory>
        <includes>
          <include>**/*.txt</include>
          <include>**/*.jpg</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>
    </resources>

</build>
```

Notice how my folder, called my-resources, is not placed under main, it's placed under src. Of course, without telling Maven about your resource in the pom it won't do anything for you.

I didn't check your code, but there's how to tell Maven to pack your resources into your jar for you. And at a glance at your code, when working from inside a jar, you need to prefix your filename with a '/'  because it's now using a relative path, not an absolute path.

getResourceAsStream("logging.properties") works outside a jar.

getResourceAsStream("/logging.properties") is what you need inside a jar.

Comment: The question is not about how to override where props are. It's about re-packaging them w/o rebuilding the whole project.